# How do I interpret numbers like 0``-24.779598336747533$

Tags: number-representation

A numerical calculation leads to the following strange output. I converted it to `InputForm` and it looks like this:

```
0``-24.779598336747533*x^12 + 
0``-31.3434482561143*x^10 + 
0``-36.976730685941334*x^8 + 
0``-42.01951644679487*x^6 + 
0``-46.53327583190665*x^4 + 
0``-50.455781380077426*x^2 + 
0``-53.44620028868298
```

Why the coefficients of the polynomial looked like this?

Comment: They're [Arbitrary-Precision Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html). The number after the double back-tick indicates the [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html).  They're all forms of zero.

Comment: @MichaelE2: If I call the polynomial to be P and try to find its roots with command "Solve[P== 0, x]". I got empty output "{}".

Comment: Yes, because all the coefficients are equal to zero.  One might speculate why you don't get `{{}}` (implies all `x` are solutions).  I suppose because it's only approximately zero, but I think one could still argue that `{{}}` would also be an appropriate answer.

Comment: It looks like you need to increase the precision in your numerical calculation, maybe by quite a lot, since the constant term indicates a rounding error of more than `10^53`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks a lot! I used "$MaxExtraPrecision = 200" and it worked fine for me now. Best regards!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: Highlight the double ticks and press `F1` and you will get a link to the documentation for [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html).

Comment: @BobHanlon: got it. Thanks!